# Does scrollViewWillScrollToTop: exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollviewdelegate

Apple documentation says that scrollViewWillScrollToTop: will be called as part of the UIScrollViewDelegate protoco. However, this method doesn't seem to exist even when I recursively grep through the /Developer folder. I don't see where this method is being called nor its prototype. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to this?

> This gesture works on a single visible scroll view; if there are
>   multiple scroll views (for example, a date picker) with this property
>   set, or if the delegate returns NO in scrollViewWillScrollToTop:,
>   UIScrollView ignores the request. After the scroll view scrolls to the
>   top of the content view, it sends the delegate a
>   scrollViewDidScrollToTop: message.

It's a typo in the docs. They meant to say `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`. You can see they are mentioning returning a BOOL value, and `will...` delegate methods usually don't return anything. The ones starting with `should...` on the other hand do.

I suggest you report this by clicking the "It's good, but..." link in the footer of the doc. I will do the same.

[image: screenshot of documentation footer]